# Java Processing ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I'm trying to follow some simple tutorials for using Processing in Java with Eclipse [(This one specifically)](https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/), and I am coming up with a weird runtime error while trying to launch even the most basic of programs.

This is my code, basically an exact copy from the tutorial:

```
package processingTest;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class UsingProcessing extends PApplet{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("UsingProcessing");
    }

    public void settings(){
        size(300,300);
    }

    public void setup(){
        fill(120,50,240);
    }

    public void draw(){
        ellipse(width/2,height/2,second(),second());
    }
}
```

There's no compiling errors, it all looks fine until I run it. When I do, though, it just spits this out:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: UsingProcessing
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10706)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10513)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10495)
    at processingTest.UsingProcessing.main(UsingProcessing.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: UsingProcessing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10699)
    ... 3 more
```

I'm pretty lost with this. I've researched around for a few hours and come up with nothing, I think I just don't know what to be looking for. If there's any more information needed, I'll be glad to give it.

Things I've tried:

- Reinstalling Processing
- Reinstalling Java
- Reinstalling Eclipse
- Including all the other misc packages from Processing
- Messing around with syntax with `PApplet.main("UsingProcessing");`

Comment: Are you running it as a Java Application or an Applet?

Comment: A Java Application. Should I be doing it as something else? How do I do that in Eclipse?

`Run > Run As` only has Java Application as an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you posted includes the following sentence:

> NOTE: If your class is part of a package other than the default package, you must call PApplet's main using the package name as well, like this:
>
> PApplet.main("packageName.ClassName");

instead of `PApplet.main("UsingProcessing")`

you should call `PApplet.main("processingTest.UsingProcessing")`

(Your package name is found at the top of your class declaration file.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that was a thing. Thank you again!

Comment: @LilahSahay Just to add to Rick's great answer(+1), you can also use `PApplet.main(UsingProcessing.class.getCanonicalName());` which will get the fully qualified class name(including the package name)